# Move files from subfolder to current folder

Tags: bash, shell

Say my files on a Ubuntu server are like: `/folder1/folder2/`

I am in `folder1` currently, and I want to move all files/folders (recursive) from `folder2` to the current folder.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

shorter version:

```
mv folder2/* .
```

Answer (score 3):

`mv /folder1/folder2/* /folder1/`

Answer (score 3):

there is a caveat to be aware of if you have invisible files (starting with '.') in your folder. dotglob (*) won't expand (and mv won't move) invisible files unless you change it's behaviour with `shopt`. `shopt -s dotglob` to expand invisible files and `shopt -u dotglob` to switch back to default.

Answer (score 0):

recursively move files to current folder:

```
find -type f -exec mv -v {} . \;
```

be aware that you won't be overwriting existing files.

Comment: You should have explained how that will behave differently from the earlier answers and in what circumstances that would be desirable.

Comment: For instance, this would work when there are more files than can fit into one shell command.  Or you're in a shell that doesn't support globbing.